# Formatting date month in PowerShell

Tags: date, powershell, format

I need to format the previous date to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

For example, today is `May 25,2016`. Therefore I need the output '`2016-05-24`'.

```
$a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-mm-dd')
Write-Output $a
```

When I run the code I get `2016-44-24` which is incorrect.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mm` specifies `The minute, from 00 through 59`
[Source.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

You have to use [uppercase for month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```